# Pypy and Matplotlib error in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pypy

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7, and I have set up a virtual environment (virtualenv) using a **pypy** interpreter.
I even installed succeffully the **matplotlib** library.

However, we it comes to using it on my own code I get this error messagge:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "my_script.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>   File "/home/.../venv/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 115, in 
>       _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
>   File
>   "/home/.../venv/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
>       globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
>   File "/home/.../venv/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
>   File "/home/.../venv/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       **from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg RuntimeError: Cannot dlopen tkinter module file**

What can I do to fix it?

**EDIT:** The solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) is the same, but I think that the problem (pypy and matplotlib) and the error message are quite different.

Comment: Try to use another back end: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37605654/2666859

Comment: Thank you! 
It helped me! However, as I reed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined

You should change the backend before importind pyplot, otherwise it doesn't work.

If you write an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the 'backend' in matplotlib in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python)

Comment: @pingul You are right if you mean that the solution is the same, but I think that the problem (pypy and matplotlib) and the error message are quite different; as many people search in Google just typing their problems, I think that also this question could be useful :)