# Batch job fails when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, batch-processing

I try to execute the following simplified batch job on my linux machine:

```
root@kali:~/Test_plots# ls
batch_job.txt  plot.py
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more plot.py 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,4)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("test.png")
print "done"
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more batch_job.txt 
python plot.py | tee output.txt
root@kali:~/Test_plots# batch < batch_job.txt 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 30 at Sat Jan 13 22:35:00 2018
root@kali:~/Test_plots# atq
30  Sat Jan 13 22:35:00 2018 = root
root@kali:~/Test_plots# atq
root@kali:~/Test_plots# ls
batch_job.txt  output.txt  plot.py
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more output.txt
root@kali:~/Test_plots#
```

The job should execute `plot.py` and save the terminal output to `output.txt`. The job seems to fail because the `output.txt` is empty.

If I execute the job manually, it succeeds:

```
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more batch_job.txt 
python plot.py | tee output.txt
root@kali:~/Test_plots# which sh
/bin/sh
root@kali:~/Test_plots# sh
# python plot.py | tee output.txt
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
done
# exit
root@kali:~/Test_plots# ls
batch_job.txt  output.txt  plot.py  test.png
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more output.txt 
done
```

The plot and the `output.txt` was created correctly.

Is there any logging where I could check why the batch job failed?

**EDIT**
If I comment out the `plt`-lines in the script, the batch job finishes correctly.

```
root@kali:~/Test_plots# ls
batch_job.txt  plot.py
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more plot.py 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,4)
y = np.sin(x)
#plt.plot(x,y)
#plt.savefig("test.png")
print "done"
root@kali:~/Test_plots# batch < batch_job.txt 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 34 at Sun Jan 14 00:02:00 2018
root@kali:~/Test_plots# atq
root@kali:~/Test_plots# ls
batch_job.txt  output.txt  plot.py
root@kali:~/Test_plots# more output.txt 
done
root@kali:~/Test_plots#
```

**EDIT2**
According to the comment of @match, I changed the content of the file `batch_job.txt` to `python plot.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt`. Now I obtain the following error:

```
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 5, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,y)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3307, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 950, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 586, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_fig
ure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1822, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Why is the DISPLAY variable invalid? If I execute the script manually (as I stated in the top) in the shell `/bin/sh` that used by the batch job, it works.

Comment: What is the working directory used by `batch`? What happens if you use absolute filenames (e.g. `plt.savefig("/tmp/test.png")` or `tee /tmp/output.txt` ?

Comment: @match I tried to use absolute paths... but still only an empty `output.txt` is created.

Comment: The next thing to test is if a simple job runs successfully. Such as putting `echo "Hello" | tee output.txt` in `batch_job.txt`

If that works, then I'd assume that the python script is crashing for some reason - in which case change `batch_job.txt` to contain `python plot.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt` to catch stderr as well as stdout.

Comment: @match Thanks for the tip how to catch stderr! Finally, I get an error. I paste it in EDIT2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, a search for the error in **EDIT2** was successful: [_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)