# setting $DISPLAY environment variable in Google Colab when using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, environment-variables, google-colaboratory

I have a simple python script which use the tkinter library to create the simple form
this script perfectly work on jupyer notebook and on local machine, but when I want to run in the google colab , it throws the following issue

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2021                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2022         interactive = 0
-> 2023         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2024         if useTk:
   2025             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

how can I set this param for such GUI script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colab runs your code on a cloud VM that has no attached display. There is no way for a package like tkinter to access the display of your own machine when the code is running remotely: you'll have to run your code locally instead.

Comment: You are correct. However, I was able to make this work on my colab. Please see my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478228/tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-in-google-colab