# how to install tkinter pacakage on the google colab

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax

could't able to install the tkinter python pacakage on google colab it's showing the invalid syntax error

"code"
pip3 install tkinter

"error"
File "", line 1
pip3 install tkinter
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You cannot install `tkinter` using `pip3`.  Also you cannot run tkinter application on google colab as there is no graphical environment, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092329/setting-display-environment-variable-in-google-colab-when-using-tkinter).

Comment: thank you it means now i have install some idle to run the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)