# TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"

Tags: python

I am using the following imports

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
```

but having this error in colab....

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-80b673e2c2ca> in <module>()
----> 1 base = Tk()

/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2021                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2022         interactive = 0
-> 2023         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2024         if useTk:
   2025             self._loadtk()

TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in google's colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478228/tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-in-googles-colab)

Comment: Yes! Colab doesn't support this library fully..