# Python tkinter (and hence IDLE) is not working in WSL terminal

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

Idk why I got this errors when trying to open IDLE in WSL terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1485, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

Install XMing on your machine.  Make sure it is running before you start WSL.

In WSL, change your .profile.  At the bottom append

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Close your WSL window and reopen.

You can then run any X application including idle.

Comment: XMing has not been updated for a long time.  Better use `VcXsrv`.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE is an application with GUI that requires X11 or Wayland to be installed on the system.
The "no $DISPLAY environment variable" error means that the system has no displays excluding terminals.
"no display name" means that you did not provide a display to display IDLE on.