# Are there settings in Jupyter notebooks to make Tkinter GUI work?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm learning to use Tkinter for another program I'm writing. This code works in Spyder and on a friends Jupyter notebook, but it does't work on mine. Is there something in the settings of my Jupyter notebook I need to change to make it work?

This is the error message I get:

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = Tk()

window.title("Hello World")
window.geometry('1500x1500')


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

Comment: I had already tried everything on that page. No success.