# Ubuntu: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

So I'm trying to run a python GUI using tkinter from Ubuntu command line, on Windows 10, and get the following error:

```
brandon@DESKTOP-V5LTF5T:~$ python3 MainApp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MainApp.py", line 14, in <module>
    root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

If you are using the `matplotlib` library then use this question: [_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

However, this question is for people using the `tkinter` library only

Comment: Have you searched this site for an answer. There are dozens of questions related to this error.

Comment: What do you mean by "from Ubuntu command line, on windows 10". Ubuntu and Windows 10 are completely separate operating systems.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, they deal with MatplotLib and Putty services, not purely tkinter applications and Ubuntu, running Ubuntu from windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot run active GUI's inside a bash terminal unless they download external software. The following tutorial is how I found out how to solve this problem: http://pjdecarlo.com/2016/06/xming-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-x11-window-system-running-from-windows-10-subsystem-for-linux.html

1. Download xming x server: A free display server for windows operating systems, simply allows you to display gui's and other fancy things from terminals: This is where I found it: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ , then run the server and it should appear in the lower right hand of the taskbar
2. Run the following command from bash/ubuntu:
   `brandon@DESKTOP-V5LTF5T:~$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`, this sets the DISPLAY variable to the local host of the newly installed xming x xerver.
3. Now run your GUI! `brandon@DESKTOP-V5LTF5T:~$ python3 MainApp.py`