# Python isnt recognizing basic graphics functions

Tags: python

Python is not understanding when I use basic circle or rectangle functions. I think it may be an import issue.

This program below should make a caterpillar:

```
from graphics import *

NUM_CIRCLES = 15

circposy = get_height() / 2
diameter = get_width() / NUM_CIRCLES
radius = diameter / 2
for i in range(NUM_CIRCLES):
  circ=Circle(radius)
  circ.set_position(radius + diameter * i,circposy)
  if i % 2 == 0:
     circ.set_color(Color.red)
  else:
     circ.set_color(Color.green)
  add(circ)
```

But instead, I get an error:

```
File "ewfrew.py.save", line 7, in <module>
    circposy = get_height() / 2
NameError: name 'get_height' is not defined
```

Is there another library I need to import For python to understand? Ive tried this on different websites and got the same output

Comment: What is the `graphics` module? Where'd you install it from? Where's its documentation? Where is `get_height` defined? If it's in `graphics`, why didn't you do `graphics.get_height()`?

Comment: And where is `get_height()` defined? Should it be `something.get_height()`?

Comment: @G.Anderson : The OP used `from graphics import *` so it shouldn't be `graphics.get_height()`, just `get_height()` (assuming that `get_height()` exists in `graphics`)

Comment: I've found three different `graphics.py`, https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/#files , https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py , and http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html .  Can you please specify which one it is, or is it something different?

Comment: @LakshyaRaj it could also be a bound method of an object, which would require an object to call it on like `circle.get_height()`

Comment: sorry I was away, this is the graphics module https://www.pas.rochester.edu/~rsarkis/csc161/python/pip-graphics.html

Comment: can also change your import to `import graphics as graphics` to allow you to call `graphics.get_height()`

Comment: @CarriedNub I downloaded the module and had a look at the `graphics.py`, it doesn't have a `get_height()` method.

Comment: Ive tried `graphics.get_height()` but it then said `NameError: name 'graphics' is not defined`

Comment: @RocketHazmat oh really, I used to code on a website where you used `get_height()` I thought they were all the same

Comment: @CarriedNub I'm assuming this is for a college class (since the module is from UofR).  Did your professor give you documentation for this module?  Is this your code or is it the professor's example?  The `graphics.py` module does not have a `get_height()` method.  it does, however, have a `Image.getHeight()` method.  I'd ask for proper documentation and try to update your code to match it.

Comment: @CarriedNub There is no "official" `graphics` module.  This seems to be one created the school/professor for a class.  Since there is no official `graphics`, every module is free to use whatever methods they want.  I'd ask the professor for the docs for this module :-)

Comment: Oh ok sorry for not specifying this, This is some old high school simple code, and Ive just been looking up how to get a graphics library to make this code work again

Comment: @CarriedNub You may have to try to find the old module you were using.  Or find a new module (one not from a college class) and port this code over to the new module.  I'd suggest not using this one and moving to another graphics module.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help Ill do that