# Tkinter issues in Berkeley PacMan Project - tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

apologies for asking what may be a stupid question.

After trying to set a venv in conda, setting up my own custom venv, re-installing Python 2.7.18 2 times, restarting and such, I still get this issue when I try to run the pacman code from Berkeley.

Any hints on why this would be?

Tkinter should be **inherently** already in Python 2.7, so I am not sure why it's going ham on me.
Even after using the exe of Python 2.7 in the C://Python27 folder I am still getting issues

The IDE I'm using is PyCharm.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pacman.py", line 681, in <module>
    runGames( **args )
  File "pacman.py", line 647, in runGames
    game.run()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Asus/Documents/GitHub/pacman/search/game.py", line 569, in run
    self.display.initialize(self.state.data)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Asus/Documents/GitHub/pacman/search/graphicsDisplay.py", line 171, in initialize
    self.startGraphics(state)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Asus/Documents/GitHub/pacman/search/graphicsDisplay.py", line 186, in startGraphics
    self.make_window(self.width, self.height)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Asus/Documents/GitHub/pacman/search/graphicsDisplay.py", line 266, in make_window
    "CS325 Pacman")
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Asus/Documents/GitHub/pacman/search/graphicsUtils.py", line 72, in begin_graphics
    _root_window = Tkinter.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1828, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable

Comment: Seems like you are running the script in WSL, then you need to install/run a X-server in Windows and set the DISPLAY environment variable inside WSL.