# TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have a python code:

```
import turtle
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 
###############
myPen = turtle.Turtle()
```

I've installed all libraries but I have this error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in line:
myPen = turtle.Turtle()`
```

Comment: Look at this question it may help: [_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

Comment: What prints `print(turtle.__file__)`?

Comment: Where are you running this code? What is your environment?